# What are the benefits of using Buffer<TSource> in Reverse method

Tags: c#, buffer

Looking at some of the code `System.Linq` I've come across some examples of `Buffer<TSource>` being used.

In the example of `Enumemerable.ReverseIterator` what is the benefit of using a Buffer?

```
private static IEnumerable<TSource> ReverseIterator<TSource>(
                                                        IEnumerable<TSource> source)
    {
      Buffer<TSource> buffer = new Buffer<TSource>(source);
      for (int i = buffer.count - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        yield return buffer.items[i];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well *something* needs to read the entirety of the sequence, so that it can then return them in the reverse order. `Buffer<TSource>` is one option here, and an efficient one - but it *could* be implemented with `ToArray()` or `ToList()`. A buffer allows an "oversized" array to be created (in the same way as it would for a list, but with less versioning etc) without the final "trim" step which would be present in `ToArray`.

You might find some of my [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) (my reimplementation of LINQ to Objects for fun and education) articles interesting, including:

- [`ToArray`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/02/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-24-toarray.aspx)
- [Part of implementing ordering](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/06/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26c-optimizing-orderedenumerable.aspx)
- [`Reverse`](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/08/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-27-reverse.aspx)

(Deliberately in that order, as they show an evolution leading towards a similar "buffer" idea.)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Is using a buffer more efficient than using `ToArray()` or `ToList()`? As far as I can tell the constructor on `Buffer` converts the source to an array straight away.

Comment: @JamieDixon: It creates an array from it - but doesn't create a right-sized array; it can be oversized, which is fine for something like `Reverse`, which keeps track of the real size.

Comment: Awesome @JonSkeet. Thanks very much. As an aside, do you know why Buffer is marked `internal`? It looks like something that could be useful in other contexts without having to pull it out into a custom type.

Comment: @JamieDixon: I suspect it's the normal reasons - it's not useful *enough* to justify the effort of designing, testing and implementing it to be available for public consumption. Public APIs are forever, so making sure you get them right is a big job. Also, there's something to be said for keeping a public API surface small from the perspective of someone learning it.

Comment: Just viewed in this, it's great.

Answer (score 1):

Buffer is more efficient than `ToList` because a `List<T>` has some internal overhead due to validation and versioning of iterators. `ToArray` needs to to a final copy pass.

Also, Buffer is a struct and avoids one allocation.

`Buffer<T>` is an internal class that has none of these overheads. It is purely a performance optimization.